# Append unique value in Local Storage and if value is duplicate, print ("already exists")?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`I have list of college programs and whenever I click on any program ,
In my "console.log" I am getting all the details related to that particular program (eg: ProgramId , schoolId , location ,schoolName).
and now I want to add all the program details  (eg: ProgramId , schoolId , location ,schoolName) in the localStorage.

As, I click of Program1 : I want all its details(eg: ProgramId , schoolId , location ,schoolName) save in localStorage,
Similarly, when I click on Program2: It will append its program details (eg: ProgramId , schoolId , location ,schoolName) because it's a unique value.

If I click on Program 1 again , it will not append its value again and give me output like:
"Already Exist"

Previous I was doing the same thing using an array rather than Local storage, but later I realized I need to keep record of program details for one session.

I am sharing my code below, how I was doing it using an array.
Need your help to refactor my code how can I do exact same thing using the Local Storage.
`

```
getProgramDetails = (ppTermDetails) => {
      this.programDetails = ppTermDetails;
      // console.log("Program Details : >>>",this.programDetails);
      
       let selectedProgramList = [];
      if (selectedProgramList.includes(this.programDetails)) {
        console.log("Already added in the list")
      } else {
        selectedProgramList.push(this.programDetails)
      }
      console.log("Final Selected Programs List : >>>> " , this.selectedProgramList);
    }
```

`I checked all the stackoverflow questions and their solutions similar to my problem, but still not worked for me. I will be really thankful if someone help me to give its solution.`

Comment: Show us what you've tried and why that didn't work. Also, it might be more convenient to use an object to store the programs using the program ID as the object's key.

Answer (score 0):

Everything sent to localStorage must be stringified, this means what you're doing with comparing references `selectedProgramList.includes(this.programDetails)` will no longer work. Refactor your function to retrieve program details by `programId` instead of passing in the entire object.

Example.

```
const programs = [
  {
    programId: 1,
    name: 'This is a cool program'
  },
  {
    programId: 2,
    name: 'This is a not-so-cool program'
  }
];

localStorage.setItem('programs', JSON.stringify(programs));

const getProgramById = (programId) => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('programs')).filter(program => program.programId === programId)[0];
};

console.log(getProgramById(2));
```